# loop through python datetimes in specified range TypeError

Tags: python, python-2.7, datetime, for-loop, typeerror

I want to create a scatter plot for every 10 minutes in the time period specified by `t_list`. I get the error  `TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [datetime64[ns]] array with a scalar of type [bool]` in the line `df_t = df[(df['datetime']>=t & df['datetime']<t_end)]` but the type for `t` and `t_end`are both `datetime`. non of the variables are type `bool`.

```
    import pandas as pd
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from datetime import datetime, timedelta

    df_data = pd.read_csv('C:\SCADA.csv')#import data

    #format Timestamp as datetime
    df_data['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df_data['TimeStamp'] )

    #create df of time period
    df = df_data[(df_data['datetime']>= datetime(2017, 12, 23, 06,00, 00)) &
             (df_data['datetime']< datetime(2017, 12, 23, 07, 00, 00))]

    #time period I want to create 10 min plots for        
    t_list = [datetime(2017, 12, 23, 06, 00, 00), datetime(2017, 12, 23, 07, 00, 00)] 



    for t in t_list:
        t_end = t + timedelta(minutes = 10)

        #breaks here with 
        TypeError: cannot compare a dtyped [datetime64[ns]] array with a 
        scalar of type [bool]

        df_t = df[(df['datetime']>=t & df['datetime']<t_end)]
        #code continues with plotting scatter plots within the loop
```

Comment: Can you please post the output of `type(df['datetime'].iloc[0])`,  `type(t)` and `type(t_end)`?

Comment: `pandas.tslib.Timestamp`, `datetime.datetime` and `datetime.datetime`  respectively

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When boolean indexing with multiple conditions, you should wrap each single condition in brackets.

From the docs:

> Another common operation is the use of boolean vectors to filter the
>   data. The operators are: | for or, & for and, and ~ for not. **These
>   must be grouped by using parentheses, since by default Python will
>   evaluate an expression** such as df.A > 2 & df.B < 3 as df.A > (2 &
>   df.B) < 3, while the desired evaluation order is (df.A > 2) & (df.B <
>   3).

Thus, adding the brackets to your last line should work:

`df_t = df[(df['datetime']>=t) & (df['datetime']<t_end)]`

Comment: It's always something simple that I've missed. Thank you for the info